# Story addressing homosexuality

Tags: story-identification

About 15 years ago I came across a book of short stories all written in by the same author and I believe all set in a previously established universe. As I recall it's less of a sci fi story and more a human story against a sci fi backdrop.

The one story I remember revolves around a conversation between a woman and a man who is in a relationship with her brother. Homosexuality, in this society, seems to be frowned upon, so I believe she is trying to conduct something of a one-on-one intervention to help her brother. By the end of the story she has slept with the man and become pregnant.

Sound familiar to anyone? When I read it I think I was too young to really get it, and want to revisit it sometime.

Comment: How long ago is _years ago_? 5 years? 35 years?

Comment: @Daft I read it about 15 years ago, but I'm not sure when it was written

Comment: Do you remember anything about the sci-fi backdrop? Is it set in the near or distant future? Do they have a world government, flying cars, food pills? Is the story set on earth or a space colony?

Comment: @user14111 I don't remember much, but I think it was on another world but technologically wasn't too advanced. The impression i had reading it was that there were probably other books/stories set in the universe and that the stories in that particular anthology were just side stories

Comment: If you could remember *something* about the sci-fi background of the story, you could put it in the question's title to make it more descriptive...

Comment: Theodore Sturgeon's "If All Men Were Brothers, Would You Let One Marry Your Sister?" concerns incest. But I last read it decades ago and remember no details.